# Paypal sandbox showing wrong STORE name

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I have tested my paypal payment with sandbox account using my API details. Now I want to use Clients API details for sandbox and changed code accordingly. But it still redirects me to the previous store.

Any idiea what is wrong i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your code didn't change the API credentials in some way. Try to check again the new APIs that you want to use and replace the previous one.
Usually, for example in ExpressCheckout, when you initially call the SetExpressCheckout you provide the API credentials of the seller so that when the checkout is displayed you can connect to the seller shop to pay and all the money will be directed there.